# i wish to find minimum element of a list whose elements first decrease then increase

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary

I want to achieve it in `O(log n) complexity`.using the idea of `binary search` it can be achieved . I put it this way: let L be a list ;`L= [12,10,9,7,6,5,8,9,11]` so the expected outcome should be `5`. Is there a simple algorithm in `python` to do it?

```
def binse(l,lo,hi):
    n =len(l)
    lo = 0
    hi =n
    mid =(lo+hi)//2
    if (hi-lo)<2:
       return lo
    if l[mid]<l[mid-1] and l[mid]<l[mid+1]:
       return l[mid]
    elif l[mid]<l[mid-1] and l[mid]>l[mid+1]:
       return binse(l,mid+1,hi)
    elif l[mid]>l[mid-1] and l[mid]<l[mid+1]:
       return binse(l,lo,mid)
    else:
       return

l = [13,11,5,6,7,8,9,11,13]
lo =0
hi =len(l)
print(binse(l,lo,hi))
```

Comment: Whats wrong with ```min(L)```?

Comment: @wnnmaw He wants O(log(n)), `min(L)` is O(n).

Comment: So you want to find the minimum in a _sorted rotated array_.

Comment: _"Is there a simple algorithm in python to do it?"_ Yes, there is. (hint: that algorithm is "binary search".)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798296/find-the-max-and-min-of-an-increasing-then-decreasing-list) might help.

Comment: Do you realize that you're discarding the supplied value for the `hi` parameter in this line: `hi = n`?

Comment: yeah finally got it working.removed lo and hi values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def mini(lis):
s, e = 0, len(lis)-1
while True:
    m = (s+e)/2
    if lis[m] > lis[m+1]:
        s = m
    elif lis[m-1] < lis[m]:
        e = m+1
    else:
        return m
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You said it - use binary search.  At each probe, take two successive entries and determine whether the values are increasing or decreasing.  Based on that, you know which region to further sub-divide.

BTW, I'm ignoring the case of equality

Update based on posted code:

1. The first thing binse does is overwrite the lo and hi parameters - bad!
2. The `return lo` line is clearly wrong as it is not returning an array value
3. Need to be a bit careful about some edge cases including getting near the endpoints and also when you have a sequence of equal values
4. The last "return" is also clearly wrong as it has no value.

The first item is the reason you are seeing the infinite recursion.

Comment: can you suggest me the pseudo code because I tried something like that and  got maximum recursive depth exceede error.

Comment: Then post your code and I'm sure somebody will help you.  Users of this site much prefer to work from code.  You may notice the question has many downvotes - I suspect that is at least in part a reaction to the lack of code.

Comment: def binse(l,lo,hi):
 n =len(l)
 lo = 0
 hi =n
 mid =(lo+hi)//2
 if (hi-lo)<2:
  return lo
 if l[mid]<l[mid-1] and l[mid]<l[mid+1]:
  return l[mid]
 elif l[mid]<l[mid-1] and l[mid]>l[mid+1]:
  return binse(l,mid+1,hi)
 elif l[mid]>l[mid-1] and l[mid]<l[mid+1]:
   return binse(l,lo,mid)
 else:
  return
 
l = [13,11,5,6,7,8,9,11,13]
lo =0
hi =len(l)
print(binse(l,lo,hi))

Comment: Actually, I recommend adding it to the question in a properly formatted manner.  Reading it in a comment just makes my brain hurt.